# Is my query for Hibernate retrieving thousands of duplicate records before removing with distinct?

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, heap-memory

In my Java application I have a class Journey which among other things has a One-to-Many relationship with ActiveDateRange, which represents details (dates) to when the Journey is operational.

Journey also has a One-to-Many relationship with the stops that the Journey is scheduled to make, usually 10-30 stops per journey.

```
class Journey{
...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "journey", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private SortedSet<ActiveDateRange> activeDateRanges = new TreeSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "journey", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private SortedSet<JourneyStop> stops = new TreeSet<>();
...
}
```

```
class ActiveDateRange{
...
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "valid_start", nullable = false)
    private Date validStart;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "valid_end", nullable = false)
    private Date validEnd;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "journey_id", nullable = false)
    private Journey journey;
...
```

```
class JourneyStop{
...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "journey_id", nullable = false,
            foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_journey_stops_journey_id"))
    private Journey journey;
...
```

I'm attempting to retrieve all Journeys with their linked ActiveDateRanges and JourneyStops for a date range, so to start I've already retrieved a large list of journey_ids from the ActiveDateRange table in a separate query.

Using these IDs in an IN query, I'm seeing a massive increase in used heap space while the below query executes:

```
StringBuilder queryBuilder = new StringBuilder();
queryBuilder.append("SELECT DISTINCT j FROM ")
    .append(Journey.class.getSimpleName())
    .append(" j ")
    .append(" LEFT JOIN FETCH j.activeDateRanges rg ")
    .append(" LEFT JOIN FETCH j.stops where j.id in (:journeyIds)");

Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery(queryBuilder.toString());
query.setHint(QueryHints.HINT_PASS_DISTINCT_THROUGH, false);
...
```

There's roughly 50K Journeys in the table, my question is as each Journey has multiple ActiveDateRanges (sometimes up to 100) associated with it, and each Journey also has on average 20 JourneyStops associated, is this causing a massive duplication in the data during query execution before the DISTINCT removes these duplicates?

Initially I've thought that I'm experiencing n * m rows retrieved with the join to ActiveDateRanges and then each of these is then joined to the JourneyStops resulting in a lot of duplication of data.

The heap usage increases linearly up to 8GB during this query, but once it finishes, the usage drops to less than 1GB as expected for normal operation. I'm looking to resolve this bottleneck as I don't want to keep a very large heap allocated for this single query.

Comment: The DISTINCT is very inefficient here and not needed to begin with if you change the `LEFT JOIN`s to EXISTS conditions - I don' know how to do that in HQL though.

Comment: You should use a paging mechanism. Hibernate supports it.